# What type is the best to present service/services with schema.org?

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I want to present my services i.e. programming, analysis with use schema.org types. What type the best suits to present this information.

I thinking about `Product` but not sure since services is not tangible and countable. I think also about `Offer` but it is little too general.

What you think - what type suits for services/service?

Answer (score 0):

At http://schema.org/Product it says (bold by me):

> A product is **anything** that is made available **for sale**—for example, a pair of shoes, a concert ticket, or a car. **Commodity services, like haircuts, can also be represented using this type.**

So if you *sell* your programming/analysis services, using `Product` is fine.